# Dojo Enhancedgrid filter: How to set custom options in drop-down autoComplete

Tags: drop-down-menu, filter, dojo

I am using the Dojo v1.8.1 + Enhancedgrid + Filter plugin and I would like to set up custom options menu for the autoComplete drop-down on one of the columns. How can I do this?

More to the problem:
One of my columns is a coma separated list of strings, this set of strings is finite and known (arround 40 different strings). As an example, let's say the column looks like this for several rows:
Row 1 : apple, banana, pineapple
Row 2 : apple, pineapple
Row 3 : banana
Row 4 : pineapple, strawberry

If I set this column in the Filter plugin as: datatype:"string", autoComplete: true, the options presented on the filter auto-complete drop-down menu are:
apple, banana, pineapple
apple, pineapple
banana
pineapple

However, I would like those options presented to the user as:
apple
banana
pineapple

So that the filter selects any row that 'contains' the string selected by the user. Is this possible?

You may argue that a coma separated list of strings is not the best way to present this data do the user. I am still able to change this, so if you have any other idea, please let me know. However, this column should be filterable.

Thanks in advance for your time and your help,

Oriol